# Font Changes after importing \usepackage{graphicx}

Tags: fonts, graphics, fontsize, overleaf

I have a strange issue with my dissertation, after trying to importing an image to my text and importing graphicx then it changes my font size, I don't seem to figure this out yet.
Here is my code,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\setromanfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\author{Stamatis Papangelou}
\title{Thesis}
\date{July 2020}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\titleformat{\section}{\sffamily\upshape\bfseries\huge}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\sffamily\upshape\bfseries\large}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\sffamily\upshape\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{} 



\usepackage[backend=biber,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}



\section{Introduction}
\vspace{7mm} 
This file contains the basic formatting instructions and guidelines on how to write your dissertation, according to the School’s requirements. Word Styles are being used extensively for the formatting of basic elements, such as titles, legends etc. Minor modifications are permitted with the agreement of the supervisor.
\subsection{Level 2}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Level 3}
\blindtext

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{pow.png}
%\caption{Proof-of-Work Algorithm}
\end{figure}



\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```

and here are some screenshots,
[image: Without]

[image: With]

Comment: you first screenshot shows an error. Beside this your font looks quite similar, but the page size could change as graphicx sets the pdf sizes.

Comment: Unrelated but note that  in `\bfseries\myfont` the \bfseries does not make the font bold as you have defined `\myfont` using the lowest level `\font` primitive so bypassing all of LaTeX's font mechanisms.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I re-uploaded the picture, it changes the font size to be more specific, and I want the initial font size in my document :)

Comment: sorry your example doesn't produce this, and a screenshot can not be tested.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes I know it is also an issue that I haven't yet resolved, I would appreciate your help :)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that is why I have also included my code, it is exactly the same I use in the screenshots

Comment: No, your code doesn't produce "Introduction".

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I edited the code, try again maybe :)

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just a different zoom factor applied in the PDF viewer? Without seeing all page boundaries, it's hard to tell. The line breaks all seem identical, in any case.

Comment: Well the font doesn't change. The only thing that change for me is that the pdf is A4 without graphicx, and letter format with graphicx.

Comment: including an image can make the fonts appear bold in some cases of malformed images but just including the package seems unlikely to affect the fonts